# openCV2 not displaying image correctly (grey area added)

Tags: python, opencv

My goal is to simply display image using openCV2. Here is the code:

```
import cv2
img2 = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is how original image looks:
[image: original image]

Here is how openCV is displaying it:
[image: openCV]

I cannot understand why there is a grey area added?

This on Python 3.4.3, openCV 3.1.0 and Win 7

Comment: That grey area has nothing too do with your image. Its just part of image display.

Comment: Do you know when I should expect grey area to show up? I have an example where different image is displayed without grey area.

Comment: This is a part of image display, your image remains unaffected.

Comment: You dont need to worry about grey area.

Comment: the minimum window size/width is bigger than your image.

Comment: @Micka, you can post it as official answer, if you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've observed that the opencv highgui windows have some minimum width.

If your image is smaller than that minimum window size, the rest of the space is filled with whatever is in the window buffer atm.
This might not be a problem, if you always render images of same (too small) size, but it might give unwanted behaviour if you first render a big image and afterwards an image that is too small, because some pixels of the big image will still be displayed. When I face this problem I typically either resize my too small image or render a black image before rendering a too small image.